# 「[況]{いわん}や」 and 「[況]{ま}して」 usages

Tags: words, usage

I just learned about  況や and 況して, I tried to search for some detailed grammar point but nothing...

Are they the same? I saw both mean "not to mention..." but they seem different from the way I saw them used.

Can they be used in everyday life?

> 誰にも倒されない・・・況してお前だ！ : I will not be defeated... certainly not by you!

Is it correct if I say that? If yes what does it change to add a 「や」 to 「況して」?

> 日本の経済はやばいよね。況や起こってる政治問題。: The economy of Japan is in a bad shape... Not to mention the current politic issues.

Is this one correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

いわんや is archaic and is rarely used in the everyday language. However, まして or ましてや is still used. Examples would be:

> 魚も食べられないのだから、まして肉など論外だ
>   魚も食べられないのだから、ましてや肉など論外だ

They both have the same meaning, but ましてや gives a bit more emphasis and is also a bit more archaic.

To your examples:
`誰にも倒されない・・・況してお前だ！` does sound ungrammatical, you'd have to say something like `誰にも倒されない・・・況してお前にはな！`.

Same for `日本の経済はやばいよね。況や起こってる政治問題`. You'd have to change it to e.g.:`日本の経済はやばいよね。況や今の政治問題はもっとやばい。`

Comment: First thank you for your great answer that`s exactly what I needed! And yes my sentences sounded wrong to me thanks for correcting!